# Relative error while importing items in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, scrapy, scrapy-item

I'm learning Python and how to use Scrapy. 
I've been scraping "http://quotes.toscrape.com/" and everything worked well until I tried to organized data using items. 
It seems the error is

```
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
```

I have not been able to find the proper way to import items so your help would be highly appreciated!

Here is the code of my spiders:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"                                                    
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):

         items = QuotetutorialItem()                                  
         all_div_quotes = response.css("div.quote")                   

         for quotes in all_div_quotes:                                

            title = quotes.css("span.text::text").extract()
            author = quotes.css(".author::text").extract()
            tag = quotes.css(".tag::text").extract()

            items["title"] = title
            items["author"] = author
            items["tag"] = tag

            yield items
```

The code of items.py:

```
import scrapy


class QuotetutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()
```

And here the structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why I generally advise is to append your project's path to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/quotetutorial/"
```

and inside your `quotes_spider.py` use:

```
from quotetutorial.items import QuotetutorialItem
```

Now if you want to import package in `items.py` from say `quotes_spider.py`, the following should do the trick:

```
from quotetutorial.spiders.quotes_spider import QuotetutorialItem
```

---

Alternatively, the following will also work:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/quotetutorial/quotetutorial/"
```

and then:

```
from items import QuotetutorialItem
```

or

```
from spiders.quotes_spider import QuotetutorialItem
```

Comment: Thanks. Concerning the line 
`  export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/quotetutorial/"   ` should I write it in the terminal directly?

Comment: I added the path using ` sys.path.append(C:\Users\fiers\Documents\Scrap\Lecon_scraping\quotetutorial\quotetutorial) ` but the result is the same right? However I now have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'items'

Comment: @Rico Are you sure that sys.path.append is before your imports?

Comment: @Rico Also, if you go with sys.path.append then you have to place it inside all of your files.