# Run Scrapy from a Script - Issues with Item Import

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run multiple spiders, to do this I want to run Scrapy as a script using what i saw in their documentation about CrawlerProcess. However, I want to use the Item I create with the different scrapy.Field objects which is inside the parent folder of where I am running the crawling script, here is a quick example to show what I am trying to achieve and how the folders are arranged with a project in scrapy:

[image]

The error i get is as follows:

[image]

After researching I cam across Relative Imports however doing this just results in this error message :
[image]

I am Showing images So you can see how the folders are arranged to help understand my issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671252/relative-error-while-importing-items-in-scrapy). Please re-upload your code as text, and add items.py

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an `__init__.py` file in the root directory.
It should be like this.

[image: scrapy project structure]

I assume you had an issue while creating the project.

For your case -

`scrapy startproject example example` to create the project

Then create a spider inside `spiders` directory.

cd to `spiders` directory and run the command (which you already did)

`C:\users\.....\ExampleFolder\example\example\spiders>python examplespider.py`